# DPC Latency issues caused by storport.sys

Tags: windows-10, lag, latency, m.2, dpc

I have been having an issue with DPC latency. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to fix it, but I have failed to find a solution.

To begin, I first noticed this issue after I cloned my Samsung SSD to my new Samsung 960 evo m.2 drive. After playing some games like battlegrounds, dark souls, and final fantasy, I noticed that each one of them would microstutter every 30 minutes or so with a buzzing noise. They last for only about a second, and then the game continues like nothing happened. I did some research and found out about DPC latency, so I downloaded LatencyMon and dpclat. I then played a game with both of them running in the background until one of these audio/video stutters occurred. As soon as it happened, I alt+tabbed to my desktop and brought the two programs into view. dpclat showed all green bars and then one massive red one followed by all small green bars again. LatencyMon just simply showed storport.sys as having the highest reported DPC routine execution time.

I am completely baffled. I uninstalled and updated all of my drivers (BIOS, audio, Internet/LAN from the ASUS website), uninstalled the 960 evo NVMe drivers to see if Windows NVM drivers fixed the issue (they didn’t), installed the latest samsung 2.2 nvme drivers again, disabled all of my overclocks, ran memtest and chkdsk, ran HD tune, used defraggler to optimize my m.2 and SSD, defragged my HDDs, updated my chipset, updated my GPU, disabled almost everything in Device Manager, turned off every service that wasn’t made by Windows, stopped every process that wasn’t made by Windows, ran `sfc /scannow` and successfully repaired corrupt files, installed (and then uninstalled after use) malwarebytes, adwcleaner, msert, and avira, used CCleaner to clean and repair registry, and others that I cannot think of at the moment. The issue still persists after all of this. It seems like the only resort would be to do a complete clean install of Windows, but I have tweaked with too many settings to optimize this PC and it would take days to get everything back to where I had it. I am hoping someone can help me, as this problem started after I cloned my 940 pro to my 960evo (the 940 pro was previously my C drive with Windows installed, but now it is the 960 evo m.2 running the OS).

Also, I don’t know if it helps, but after cloning my SSD to my m.2 Windows said it needed to be activated, so I activated it with KMS since my previous Windows 7 key wouldn’t work for some reason (I used my Windows 7 key to get a free copy of Windows 8, and then Windows 8 automatically updated to Windows 10). And I feel like this should be obvious, but running the samsung magician benchmarking tool for my m.2 shows a very high DPC latency spike for storport.sys, as does running HD tune, but I think this is just because of the heavy load the m.2 is under when using those tools. As of now, I turned my RAM and CPU overclocks back to where I had them previously before I cloned my SSD to my m.2 since they shouldn’t be the issue since I never had this program until I cloned my drive (I used samsung's migration tool to accomplish this).

Here is a quick summary of my specs (full speccy txt file and DPC checker results attached separately):

- Spec Summary:
  [W10ProV1703b15063 x64]
- Operating System:
  Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- CPU:
  AMD Ryzen 7 1700X 54 °C
- Summit Ridge 14nm Technology
- RAM:
  16.0 GB Dual-Channel Unknown @ 1529 MHz (16-18-18-36)
- Motherboard:
  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. PRIME X370-PRO (AM4) 33 °C
- Graphics:

  - BenQ XL2730Z (2560x1440@144Hz)
  - 8176MB ATI Radeon RX Vega (ATI) 33 °C
- Storage:

  - 238 GB Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series (SSD)  29 °C
  - 931 GB Seagate ST1000DX002-2DV162 (SATA) 31 °C
  - 931 GB Seagate ST1000DM003-9YN162 (SATA) 29 °C
  - 232 GB Samsung SSD 960 EVO 250 GB (Unknown)
  - 1862GB Western Digital WD Elements 25A1 USB Device (SSD) 29 °C
- Optical Drives:

  - ATAPI iHBS112 2
  - ATAPI iHAS324 B
  - ELBY CLONEDRIVE SCSI CdRom Device
- Audio:
  Realtek High Definition Audio
- Computer type: Desktop
- PSU is the EVGA Supernova 850 P2 (80 Plus Platinum), and my RAM is in dual channel slots 1 and 3.

Speccy: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8snXLdwm3VhaDV3RTlRZUEzU2c

[image]

[image]

[image]

Link to (the above) screenshots, DPC Latency, and trace files: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Dw80_fDvon_9rQiErGz0yIU1MVMyvit9RAABHzzXMOU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the ETL is missing a lot of data. open a cmd.exe as admin, run this command to capture DPC activity : **WPR -start CPU && timeout 60 && WPR -stop C:\HighDPCUsage.etl**. share the ETL. also stop latency mon during capturing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my machine for some time. I finally fixed it by going to device manager and disabling NVM controller, which is in storage controller.

Hope that it helps.